# Access exception in runtime generated expression

Tags: c#, exception, expression-trees

Well obvious case. I do some runtime magic with expressions. My unit test throws an exception because, well, what I am doing is quite complex and thus obvious to fail.

I don't know how I could possibly debug the generated delegate, so as workaround I'd like to insert a try-catch which logs the exception to the Console.

I just don't get how I can access the exception variable. The variable is exposed by the `CatchBlock`-class. But I have to pass through the body in the factory method, where it is out-of-scope.

How can I access it? I don't see any legit, non-hacky way to do this and since this is a very unusual topic, there's hardly to none documentation / information to be found on the internet.

Here's my code so far:

```
// The actual code
BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(new[] {messageParam, objectParam},
    callExpressions.ToArray());

// The catch block around it
CatchBlock catchExpression = Expression.Catch(typeof(Exception),
    Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod(nameof(Console.WriteLine),
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, CallingConventions.Any, new[] {typeof(string)},
            null),
        Expression.Call(// Here should be the ParameterExpression
            typeof(Exception).GetProperty(nameof(Exception.Message),
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetMethod)));
// The try-block for the catch
TryExpression tryExpression = Expression.TryCatch(block, catchExpression);

// Compilation ...
```

Comment: You can view the "code" expressions generate as you go in the debugger. So you can see where you are going wrong. You won't be able to see the generated code after you compile it, so as I develop, I usually just stick the final Expression.Lamba in a temp variable that I'll remove when I get it all working. That way I'll be able to see the final code. Also, as you see the code generated, it'll make more sense how everything links together -- at least it does for me :). Post your generated code if you are having issues.

Comment: Ah okay, so I can see the code when I look into the LambdaExpression before I compile it? Good to know. Well, I found my issue using the old-fashioned brainstorm-method. I passed the parameters as variables into the block, thus overriding them causing a NullReferenceException. - The issue obviously occured during execution - the code generation itself doesn't fail since it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

I was desperately trying to solve the same problem. I have the very similar reasons - tracing purposes on dynamic expressions.
The solution ended up to be as easy as using a [different overload of Expression.Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323969(v=vs.110).aspx).

Though - due to very sparse documentation and examples it was hard to find out.

So in case anybody else needs a similar functionality - here goes a very basic working example (you can replace the catch body with custom expression logging to your logger etc.):

```
var parExcep = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Exception), "exc");

MethodInfo excMsg = typeof(Exception).GetProperty("Message",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetMethod;


TryExpression tryCatchExpr =
    Expression.TryCatch(
        Expression.Block(
            Expression.Throw(Expression.Constant(new DivideByZeroException())),
            Expression.Constant("Try block")
            ),
        Expression.Catch(
            parExcep,
            Expression.Call(parExcep, excMsg)
            )
        );

Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(tryCatchExpr).Compile()());
```

Prints out:

> Attempted to divide by zero.